# Trigger for button enable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two buttons. How I can enable second button after clicking on first button using only xaml.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NewButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SecondButton, Path=IsEnabled,Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="FirstButton"  Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Style="{StaticResource NewButtonStyle}"/>
    <Button x:Name="SecondButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsEnabled="False"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add two references in order to use Interaction.Triggers and ChangePropertyAction (System.Windows.Interactivity and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions)

```
 <Button x:Name="FirstButton"  Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="SecondButton" PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
<Button x:Name="SecondButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsEnabled="False"/>
```